# can't open link via selenium while link opens manually

Tags: security, url, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate procedure of filling one form on some site. I could easily do it manually. I go to site, login and click on link - Go to form filling.

But then I run selenium test, it fails then clicks on link Go to form filling. The error is:

Internet Explorer cound not display webpage.

I guess it could be because of some security rule on this site. But I do not know how to fix it.
Could someone advice me what could be done in such occasions? Thanks

Updates:
2) Is this site AJAX heavy? - no
3) Are you using implicit or explicit timers? - I have tried explicit waits - no help
4) What code is failing and what error message does your IDE throw - the error is that driver could not find element. This element became visible after likk opens. as link is failed to open - this error is raised. so I write error message from IE as it is the root cause.
5)HtmlUnitDriver - do not try

Code:

```
            driver.get(linkToConsole);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(loginLocator)).sendKeys(login);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(passwordLocator)).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(submitButton)).click();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(goToHomePageLocator)));
    //this link doesn't open (but it works manually)
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(goToHomePageLocator)).click();
    // this element is not found and here error in IDE is raised
    driver.findElement(By.id(manualValidation)).click();
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
Unable to find element with id == myid (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30.12 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info:
Session ID: 0976b47d-caf5-42fc-9e48-5c8a8c18e624
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=9, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:12015/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:220)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
at test.java.org.fullProcess.fillConsole(FullProcess.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: What's the URL? Is this site AJAX heavy? Are you using implicit or explicit timers? What code is failing and what error message does your IDE throw ("Internet Explorer could not display webpage" sounds like it's thrown by your browser)? Does it work in modern browsers? What about HtmlUnitDriver? There's probably a solution but we need more information. :)

Comment: You forgot to _paste_ your code and the exact error message printed out by your IDE, if any. I would bet the driver is looking for the element before it loads so you need to add an implicit or explicit timer so that it doesn't look till after the element has loaded. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Protected Mode settings.

Tools --> Internet Options --> Security Tab --> Select "Enable Protected Mode" for all zones.

I assume this should be the reason for your issue.

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("ensureCleanSession", true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

Source: http://mestachs.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/selenium-best-practices/

Comment: I have used this, and it does not help